# Custom price for product not working while creating order by admin

Tags: php, magento-1.7

As a admin when i am trying to create one order (Customer->manage customers->Add product->custom price) and giving custom price for product by checking check box of custom price still in frontend and backend cart onl original price is displaying not custom price. It seems mangento having this bug.Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks !
[image: custom price]